# Detect how many monitors are connected to a pc from a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

i run a website that shouldn't allow people with more than one monitor connected to see the content.
So I need to check how many monitors are connected..
The website will be only accessed with chrome and I already tried the Google Presentation API but it detects the second monitor only if the monitors are extended and not duplicated..

Thank you

Comment: At its core this sounds like a fool's errand.  Why do you want to restrict the user in this way?  Why do you want to restrict the user to only Chrome in the first place?  What difference does it make?  Web applications just need to work in the browser, they don't need to know details about the client's hardware.  If your application needs this information for a specific purpose then what you want is an installed client application, not a website.

Comment: The users are restricted to Chrome because is a particular website and it's used in conjunction with another platform which needs an extensions that is available only to chrome.

Answer (score 4):

You can't detect monitors with javascript. Only screen width/height but if the monitors are extended, you would get the full width of both. If they are duplicated then you'd get the width of just one. Still no way to tell how many monitors are connected.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/presentation-api/ is interesting though - and I discovered this from the downvoted question, not the upvoted answer.